# What is the difference between imperative and object-oriented programming?

Tags: oop, imperative

When I look at numerous websites. Some use object-oriented programming and imperative programming interchangeably whilst others say that they are different.

I would like to know what is the difference between object-oriented and imperative and how these paradigms differ. Or if their is no difference at all.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RobK no, it really wouldn't. There are _books_ written on the subject and holy wars about the terminology. It's not answerable anywhere outside of perhaps a dissertation.

Comment: @enderland "Less bad fit" then? But we agree it certainly isn't a good fit for here.

Comment: @RobK: That's not a good enough metric for a question migration.

Answer (score 10):

This is a tough one because the terms involved often mean different things to different people.

Roughly speaking (although some would say "strictly speaking") imperative is the opposite of declarative.

Strict OO proponents would likely say that OO is declarative. See the "Object Thinking" style of OO in David West's book of that name and this blog: http://www.yegor256.com/.

OO as it is commonly practiced often "devolves" (again, others will sharply disagree) into a very procedural and imperative style where you start telling the computer what to do rather than describing and modeling the real world (in some sense) with your objects.

([Here's](https://vimeo.com/91672848) a video that might be useful. It contrasts procedural programming and OO, and for our purposes here "procedural" is roughly a synonym for "imperative".)

I know that's not a great answer, but maybe it's useful.

Comment: So is OOP almost metaphorically like a man-in-the-middle between procedual and imperative paradigms?

Comment: @attachPost, please edit your question, or ask a new one, rather than starting a discussion in comments.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean @attachPost, but I would say that OOP can be considered either imperative or declarative depending on how you define OOP. For full disclosure, I'm moving right over to the view that "good" OOP (OOP properly understood) is fundamentally declarative. The more imperative or procedural it becomes the more you're missing the point. And there ideally shouldn't be much (if any) mixing of the two approaches. This view won't go down well with many people. But you should at least be aware of the two "extremes". :)

Comment: Ah, sorry @jaco0646. What are the comments for then? (That's a genuine question, in case it comes across snarky!) Cheers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments

Comment: Thanks @jaco0646. Those answers though seem about off-topic stuff, or about not being about the post. "attachPost" and I were talking about the post. This conversation, though, _is_ perhaps off topic. So I'll leave it there...

Comment: @JohnPage _I know that's not a great answer, but maybe it's useful_ I think it is a great answer. This is common source of confusion for people comparing OOP and FP

Answer (score 3):

Coming from top to down, there are two main subtypes of imperative languages.

- Procedural languages (e.g. BASIC, FORTRAN) - where code and data are treated as completely separate, and have a simple code-operates-on-data paradigm.
- Object-oriented (OO) languages - where data and code (in the form of methods) are bundled together into objects. In OO languages, additional structure is imposed to a greater or lesser degree by metadata (such as class information).

Comment: Do not confuse programming languages with programming paradigms. Most modern languages support multiple paradigms.